# Finding a closed form for coefficients in $x^{3n}=x_0\left(a_nx+b_n+\frac {c_n}{x}\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, closed-form, recursion

Consider,
$$
x^3=x+1
$$
Let $x_0$ be a solution to the above equation. Now consider $x^{3n}$. For $n=2$ we have:
$$
x^6=(x+1)^2
$$
$$
=x^2+2x+1
$$
$$
=x\left(x+2+\frac {1}{x}\right)
$$
$$
=x_0\left(x+2+\frac {1}{x}\right)
$$
For $n=3$ we have:
$$
x^9=(x+1)^3
$$
$$
=x^3+3x^2+3x+1
$$
$$
=3x^2+4x+2
$$
$$
=x\left(3x+4+\frac {2}{x}\right)
$$
$$
=x_0\left(3x+4+\frac {2}{x}\right)
$$
Similarly for $n=4$ we have:
$$
x^{12}=x_0\left(7x+9+\frac {5}{x}\right)
$$
In general we have:
$$
x^{3n}=x_0\left(a_nx+b_n+\frac {c_n}{x}\right),
$$
Where,
$$
a_{n+1}=a_n+b_n, a_2=1,
$$
$$
b_{n+1}=a_n+b_n+c_n, b_2=2,
$$
$$
c_{n+1}=a_n+c_n, c_2=1.
$$
My question is: is there a closed form for $a_n,b_n$ and $c_n$?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The only way I know to approach this is the method of solving simultaneous recurrence relations covered in my combinatorics textbook. (For those curious: *Applied Combinatorics, Sixth Edition* by Alan Tucker: it's in section 7.5, example 5, on page 313.) The issue being, this is a very nontrivial calculation, and concerns the use of generating functions throughout. [cont.]

Comment: I tried solving it just to get the generating function for your $a_n$ terms and that in itself took several pages of scratch work (haven't even tried the other two yet) - which I'm not confident in because it's messy and there's a lot of painful algebra involved in this one, so there's plenty of room for error. Plus it all feels like it might fruitless if you're not familiar with such topics. I'm not going to say it's the *only* method, but it's the only one that I know of off-hand.

Comment: What I would try is computing $a_n$, $b_n$, and $c_n$ by computer program up to, say, n=12  and plug each sequence independently into the OEIS.

Comment: a is https://oeis.org/A095263, b is https://oeis.org/A052921 and c is https://oeis.org/A181984

Comment: The PARI program is 
? a=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]; b=a; c=a;
? a[1]=1; b[1]=2; c[1]=1;
? for (n=1, 11, a[n+1]=a[n]+b[n]; b[n+1]=a[n]+b[n]+c[n]; c[n+1]=a[n]+c[n]);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We derive generating functions for the recurrence relation:
\begin{align*}
a_{n+1}&=a_n+b_n\tag{1}\\
b_{n+1}&=a_n+b_n+c_n\qquad\qquad (n\geq 2)\tag{2}\\
c_{n+1}&=a_n+c_n\tag{3}\\
a_2&=1,b_2=2,c_2=1\\
\end{align*}

> Let $A(x)=\sum_{n\geq 2} a_nx^n, B(x)=\sum_{n\geq 2} b_nx^n, C(x)=\sum_{n\geq 2} c_n x^n$.
>
> We obtain from (1)
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n\geq 2}a_{n+1}x^n&=\sum_{n\geq 2}a_nx^n+\sum_{n\geq 2}b_nx^n\\
> \frac{1}{x}\sum_{n\geq 3}a_nx^n&=A(x)+B(x)\\
> A(x)-x^2&=xA(x)+xB(x)\\
> \color{blue}{(1-x)A(x)-xB(x)}&\color{blue}{=x^2}\tag{4}\\
> \end{align*}
>
> Since (3) and (1) have the same structure and initial condition, we get
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{(1-x)C(x)-xA(x)}&\color{blue}{=x^2}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\tag{5}\\
> \end{align*}
>
> The relationship (2):
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n\geq 2}b_{n+1}x^n&=\sum_{n\geq 2}\left(a_n+b_n+c_n\right)x^n\\
> \frac{1}{x}\sum_{n\geq 3}b_nx^n&=A(x)+B(x)+C(x)\\
> B(x)-2x^2&=xA(x)+xB(x)+xC(x)\\
> \color{blue}{(1-x)B(x)-xA(x)-xC(x)}&\color{blue}{=2x^2}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}

We take (4) - (6) and derive from them the generating functions.
\begin{align*}
(1-x)A(x)-xB(x)&=x^2\\
-xA(x)+(1-x)C(x)&=x^2\\
-xA(x)+(1-x)B(x)-xC(x)&=2x^2
\end{align*}

> Solving the equations above we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{A(x)}&\color{blue}{=\frac{x^2}{1-3x+2x^2-x^3}}\\
> &=x^2 + 3 x^3 + 7 x^4 + 16 x^5 + 37 x^6 + 86 x^7+\cdots\\
> \color{blue}{B(x)}&\color{blue}{=\frac{1-x}{x}A(x)-x}\\
> &=2 x^2 + 4 x^3 + 9 x^4 + 21 x^5 + 49 x^6 + 114 x^7 +\cdots\\
> \color{blue}{C(x)}&\color{blue}{=\frac{x}{1-x}A(x)+\frac{x^2}{1-x}}\\
> &=x^2 + 2 x^3 + 5 x^4 + 12 x^5 + 28 x^6 + 65 x^7+\cdots
> \end{align*}
>   where the expansion was done with some help of Wolfram Alpha.